# Map on page using GMAP3 is loading zoomed way out, and only zooms in after clicking the tab button a second time

Tags: jquery, google-maps, jquery-gmap3

I inherited working on this site so I'm not 100% on some variables there may be, heres what I know. Up until recently, it did work fine.

The site is using the GMAP3 5.1.1 plugin, with jQuery v1.8.2

the link is here:http://www.wcsmith.com/dc-apartments/

When click the Map View button, the map loads zoomed out.
When clicking it again, it shows zoomed in.

I tried to a couple window.resize functions to know avail.

My next step is to copy the site locally and really dive in but thought someone else may have had this problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on gmap3.min.js line 2653 you got something like this:

```
   $('#gmap_view_wrapper').gmap3({
          map: {
            options: {
              mapTypeId: "RoadMap",
              zoomControl: true,
              panControl: false,
              streetViewControl: false,
              mapTypeControlOptions: {
                mapTypeIds: ["RoadMap", google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE]
              }
            }
          },
```

add zoom desired:

```
   $('#gmap_view_wrapper').gmap3({
          map: {
            options: {
              mapTypeId: "RoadMap",
              zoomControl: true,
              zoom: 4,
              panControl: false,
              streetViewControl: false,
              mapTypeControlOptions: {
                mapTypeIds: ["RoadMap", google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE]
              }
            }
          },
```

change values from 1 to 13 if I recall good

EDIT:

on a second look, its the bounds part what's messing it up. same file the very last part:

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
         new google.maps.LatLng((points[0].lat * 0.99999), points[0].lng ),
         new google.maps.LatLng((points[0].lat * 1.00008), points[0].lng));
        for(var i = 1; i < points.length; i++) bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(points[i].lat, points[i].lng));
        gm = $('#gmap_view_wrapper').gmap3('get');
        gm.fitBounds(bounds);
  }
}
```

when removing that part map loads normally, but out of bounds, so if you tweak that part of the code, you'll get where you want. Good luck!

Comment: I changed the zoom in another location but did not see this one, so i was real hopeful, but it did not change anything after updating and deleting the cache. Thanks a lot for looking though @monxas !

Comment: thanks @monxas, that led me in the right direction. Seems odd that would be causing an issue now but maybe something on the site was updated? Either way, I was able to comment that out and change the coords. Working and no errors is great news...